# How to get value from php to input using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Hi My question is how can I get the value from php script using an ajax with a onclick event.

I have a text field and a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getid(this)">Generate ID</button>
<input type="text" name="pin" class="form-control" readonly>
```

And here is my php script named getrowcount.php

```
include_once  'conx.php';

$query ="SELECT * FROM patientprofile";
$result = $DBcon->query($query);
$count = $result->num_rows;

if ($result) {
   if($count >= 0){
       $count_res = $count += 1;
       $idnum = $count_res;
       $test = str_pad($idnum, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```

And now my problem  is how can I get the value from `$test` and put it in the input text field using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to display the output from the query in the input field.

Step 1: Add this line of code to the bottom of `getrowcount.php`:

```
echo $test;
```

Step 2: Amend your HTML so that it looks like this:

```
<form id="get">
   <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" class="form-control" readonly>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate ID">
</form>
```

Step 3: Add this script to the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#get").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input = $("#pin");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getrowcount.php",
            success: function(data) { input.val(data); }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have made a small change to the jQuery code.

Comment: Hi @The Codesee what if i use the onclick event rather than the submit button so that the page wont reload when cliccking the button.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should stop the page from refreshing when the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery method `$.get()` in your javascript script :

```
function getid(_this){
     $.get('php_script_url.php',{},function(response){
         alert(response);
         $("[name=pin]").val(response);
     })
}
```

Then in your PHP script you should add echo to the result you want to return :

```
echo $test;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you

Your PHP code :

```
<?php
    // Your database query and results store in $test
    echo $test;
?>
```

Your ajax call should be -

```
$.ajax("getrowcount.php").done(function(data) {
   $('.form-control').val(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you'd run the ajax call on button press, load the php from the ajax, in the php do an `echo` with the variable you want to use, then in the ajax success section, you'd use the returned variable.