# Select "Variable" from DB and display without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax, textinput

Is that possible to select variable in DB (such as : $username) and display their info in textbox ?

Example:

`Select : $username`

after the selection, in the text input , will show:
`$username , $usernameEmail , $usernameContactNumber`

and click on "Register", it will insert to database with the information

I have no idea how does this work. I have no problem in inserting value to database.

The only problem that I am unable to solve right now is the condition I needed.

When I choose `$username` (example: userA),
all the information of userA will be appearing in the text input below

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userdatabase";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db,$query);

<select>
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[2];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

The code above is the selection (PHP

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#get").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input = $("#username");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userregisteraccount.php",
            success: function(data) { input.val(data); }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

code above is the ajax 
so that when i choose "userName" , "userName" data will be show in the registerform

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Maybe take a look at Ajax. It’s a library for easy asynchron requests. Here a well known intro: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: followed the w3school example , unable to do it , it show option values , but when i selected , the info wont change

Comment: Read carefully the question and the accepted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964536/how-to-get-value-from-php-to-input-using-ajax-request.

Comment: Please share us your code. So we can help you better

Comment: i have the updated my code in the first post @Markus